# How to interpret the values retuen by probabiltiy density function?

Tags: density-function

`dnorm()` and `dgamma()` are used to return the density of a given distribution function. How we interpret their value? For example, if the mark of stat students is normally distributed with mean 2 and standard deviation 0.5. Then `dnorm(3,2,0.5)` will give `0.1078919`. So what does it mean? Can I say that the probability density that a student got 3 in the stat exam is 0.10?

Kindly note that I am not asking about the difference between probability density and probability. I am asking what does the value of dnorm means at a single value? How to explain the return value?

Comment: I think I found the answer. dnorm(3, 2, 0.5) is how often a stusents get 3 in stat exam  which is about 10%.

Comment: That is incorrect. If you take the distribution to be normal (which student scores won't be exactly), then the probability of scoring a $3$ is zero!

Comment: @Dave  I am not asking about probability itself. Of course it will be zero as normal is continuous.  But I am asking about dnorm. Which is the probability density which is different than the probability.

Comment: Then how do students score $3$ about $10\%$ of the time?

Comment: @Dave I mean relative frequency. Is the dnorm at a single value return the height of the density at this value? The hight is the frequency/ relative frequency.

Comment: @Dave if there is 100 students. Then 10% of them will got 3. Not the probability that a students will got 3 in the exam.

Comment: @Dave my question is not a duplicate as I am asking about the meaning of a return value or interpretation and not the difference between probability and probability density as the other question.

Comment: What happens when the `dnorm` function returns a value in excess of $1$, such as `dnorm(0, 0, 1/5)`?

Comment: @Dave dnorm can exceed 1. It is not a probability so it can exceed one. It is the f(x).

Comment: So then over $190\%$ of the students can earn $3$ if the mean if $3$ and the standard deviation is $1/5?$ `dnorm(3, 3, 1/5) = 1.99`

Comment: @Dave So, what do you think  1.99 mean?

Comment: That's answered in the duplicate thread, which specifically explains how to interpret the density: I encourage you to read it.

Comment: @whuber I have read it. But I am still confused. The density is a smooth curve of histogram. Then, the higher of any bar in histogram is the frequency of that bar. I think the same is for density. That is my point.

Comment: The height of the pdf represents density.  The comparison with a histogram is a good one when the histogram is correctly understood as representing frequency by the *areas* of the bars, not their heights.